# Where is this Nuget package coming from?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I've got a project with the following PackageReference:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="SIL.LCModel.Utils" Version="10.2.0-*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now based on the below search, I expect Nuget to resolve the package to "10.2.0-netcore0083" as desired.

```
PM> Find-Package -AllVersions -source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json SIL.LCModel.Utils -IncludePrerelease -ExactMatch | foreach { $_.Versions } | Select-Object OriginalVersion

Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.1477577
OriginalVersion   
---------------   
10.2.0-netcore0083
10.2.0-beta0033   
10.2.0-beta0032   
10.2.0-beta0031   
10.2.0-beta0027   
10.2.0-beta0026   
10.2.0-beta0025   
10.2.0-beta0024   
10.2.0-beta0023   
10.2.0-beta0022   
10.2.0-beta0011   
10.2.0-beta0007   
10.2.0-beta0006   
10.2.0-beta0005   
10.2.0-beta0004   
10.2.0-beta0002   
10.2.0-beta0001   
10.1.0
```

But it's resolving to:

```
PS C:\Users\joseph\source> dotnet list .\src\MyProject.csproj package
Project 'MyProject' has the following package references
   [netstandard2.0]:
   Top-level Package              Requested   Resolved
   > SIL.LCModel.Utils            10.2.0-*    10.2.0-restorepacking0022
```

I've cleared my nuget caches, even done a whole-drive sweep for "restorepacking" just to be sure. This happens locally and on the build server. I'm assuming it prefers this package over the "netcore0083" due to [the first example here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Support-pre-release-packages-with-floating-versions#advanced-scenarios), as opposed to taking the latest, but my real question is: Where is this package coming from?

Comment: You're looking explicitly at nuget.org for the versions... During restore, is there another package source it may be pulling from? Try running `dotnet nuget list source`. Or perform a `dotnet restore` with more verbose logging turned on to see where the packages are comig from.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The only sources are Nuget and VS Offline Packages. The logs, in spite of this, show "CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/sil.lcmodel.utils/index.json" which has the offending version. Looking into this more.

Comment: Based on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/package-base-address-resource), it seems possible that this is pulling an unlisted version? So the floating pattern for beta releases could get you stuck with a single package forever, as long as that package happens to be alphabetically last?